# How to re-render component with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm completely new to React and I'm trying to use the React Hooks. I have a functional based component and I'm using the `useState` and `useEffect` to get users from my database and display them in a table.

Now, I also have a delete button for each row of my table. When I click on the delete button, I execute a delete function which deletes the data from my database. This works well. However, the table is not updated unless I refresh the whole page completely.

How can I update (re-render) my users table once the delete is done.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
const [users, listUsers] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(GET_URL)
        .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        listUsers(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);

const deleteUser = async id => {
    await fetch(DELETE_URL, {
        //JSon message
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id: id
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        });

    alert('User Deleted.');
};
```

Comment: you should remove the user you want from the list, then call `listUsers`. One way that could look is like this `const tmp = users.filter( u => u.id !== id )` then `listUsers(tmp)` Where `tmp` is just a copy / temp array to store the users that you dont want to delete.

Comment: Have the delete URL send back the list of users as well, and set the new state in the success callback. Also, I'd always follow the naming convention: `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating your list of users state once deletion You have update your list of users state. You can do this by:

```
const deleteUser = async id => {
    await fetch(DELETE_URL, {
      //JSon message
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id: id
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    const usersUpdated = users.filter(p => p.id !== id); //Filter your list of users and remove the one for the specific id
    listUsers(usersUpdated); //This updates your state
    alert('User Deleted.');
  };
```

;)

Comment: what happens when the request fails? :/

Comment: @JohnRuddell server crash

Comment: You remove users from the client regardless of the request finishing or not. This is error prone, rather you should utilize your callbacks to keep track of the requests life cycle and or when to remove the user from the client